# Computing the coefficients of the egf of derangements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, generating-functions, permutation-cycles, derangements

> Recall that a derangement is a permutation with no fixed points and let $\mathcal{D}$ be the combinatorial class of derangements. Find the exponential generating function $D(z)$ of $\mathcal{D}$ and a formula for its coefficients $[z^n]D(z)$.

Recalling the cycle notation of permutations we see that

$$\mathcal{D} = SET(CYC_{\ge 1}(Z)),$$

so $D(z) = \exp \big( \log \big(\frac{1}{1-z}\big)-1 \big) = \frac{e^{-z}}{1-z}$. So evaluating the coefficient requires us to multiply the corresponding power series:

\begin{align}
e^{-z} \cdot \frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-z)^n}{n!} \cdot \sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^n 
= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-z)^n}{n!} \cdot \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n! \frac{z^n}{n!} 
\end{align}

Now I tried to use the multiplication rule for egfs:

$$ A(z)\cdot B(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \bigg( \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a_kb_{n-k} \bigg) \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

but this does not yield a good result. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Here is the final (and correct) computation:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-z)^n}{n!} \cdot \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n! \frac{z^n}{n!} &=  \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \bigg( \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k(n-k)! \bigg) \frac{z^n}{n!} \\ 
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \bigg( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!} (-1)^k \bigg) \frac{z^n}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \bigg( n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k }{k!} \bigg) \frac{z^n}{n!}
\end{align}

Comment: What is not good exactly? The inner sum is indeed the number of derangements, and you will find the classic formula $D_n=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$.

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: Right. Now simplify, you get a $k!$ in denominator from the binomial coefficient. There is nothing wrong here. You won't find a closed form for this sum, but it's fine. Oh wait, there is a minor error in your formula: it's $(-1)^{n-k}k!$, or $(-1)^k(n-k)!$, but not $(-1)^nk!$.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I there is still something missing.

Comment: Yes, see my comment above about $(-1)^n$. It's incorrect. Once you fix this, the sum is right. To simplify further, change the order of summation to get $k!$ instead of $(n-k)!$. And you have the formula for $D_n$ inside the parens, hence the egf of $D_n$. What would be missing?

Comment: I get it now, thanks a lot for your help.